# start next function after success

Tags: javascript, ajax, function, callback

i want to start a function after a successful ajax call. What i do now is this

```
function ajaxCall(url, types, next) {
    $.ajax({
        url: url,
        type: 'POST',
        beforeSend: function () {

            $("#plaatsMelding").append("<div id=\"" + types + "verwerkt\"><div class=\"progress-label\">" + types + " verwerken...</div></div>");
        },
        success: function (data) {
            $('#plaatsMelding').empty();
            $("#plaatsMelding").append("<div id=\"" + types + "verwerkt\"><div class=\"progress-label\">" + data + "</div></div>");
            //run next script
            if (next.length) {
                alert(next);
                next(); //this won't work because it will search for the next() function
            }

        }
    });
}
```

i start this function with this function:

```
function saveRace() {
    ajaxCall("verwerkRace.php", "race", "savePlayers");
}
```

so when that function is ready i want it to run the function "savePlayers". How can i do this?

```
function savePlayers() {
    ajaxCall("verwerkPlayers.php", "players");
}
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Don't pass a string, pass a function:

```
function saveRace() {
    ajaxCall("verwerkRace.php", "race", savePlayers);
}
```

Then in your `success` you can do this:

```
if (next) {
    next(); 
}
```

Comment: All good, but I would suggest a `typeof` verification on `next` to prevent errors.

Answer (score 2):

Just pass in the function itself:

```
function saveRace() {
  ajaxCall("verwerkRace.php", "race", savePlayers);
}
```

The JavaScript knows nothing of turning your string into a function to be called.

Comment: "into a function", not "into a function call"

Comment: @thejh At 13k reputation you're privileged to edit such typos, you know. (:

Comment: I know, but I think it's a bit rude and I want to be extra careful about introducing thinkos in other people's stuff. I'd probably have done it if it was a mismatched quote char or so.

Answer (score 0):

As suggested, pass a function instead of a string

```
function saveRace() {
    ajaxCall("verwerkRace.php", "race", savePlayers);
}
```

In success you can then check to ensure you're passing a function, and then fire it:

```
 if (next && typeof(next) === 'function') {
    next(); 
 } else {
    console.error('Error firing the callback!');
 }
```

Comment: -1 from me. If an invalid parameter was passed, you don't want to ignore the parameter. You want your code to crash as loudly and clearly as possible.

Comment: That's a ridiculous reason for a downvote, especially if this is prod code. You could write an `else` that would throw an error but letting errors blow your script is a BAD idea.

Comment: There - I updated the code so you can see the CORRECT way to approach error handling.

Comment: Why is it? If someone makes a mistake (pass a bad parameter), why would you want to ignore it? You want it to blow up while you're still in the development or testing phase, not let some stupid bug go unnoticed for months.

Comment: @Fluidbyte 'Correct' way? That's a bold statement (not to mention wrong).

Comment: Sorry if I got ahead of myself, try-throw or another option would be ideal, but letting you 'code crash as loudly as possible' is clearly not a good option.

Comment: Four lines of code, and the only benefit is that while you're developing, your app is a bit more gentle (and less explicit and clear) about telling you that you did something wrong (and where)? I'm not convinced.

Comment: Right, but if it goes to production with a just fail-loudly policy you won't be helping your cause any. Errors should be handled, not allowed to just 'blow up' your application.

Comment: Passing a bad callback parameter should cause an error as soon as the code path is used once, so a small amount of testing should catch such an error. Pretty unlikely that something like that gets into production.

Comment: Unless you're writing code which is reusable - i.e. you may not just pass one function in one instance, building for expandability may not have been the point of the question, but probably good to include in answers as a best practice.

Comment: @Fluidbyte It all depends on whether or not an error is exceptional to your expectations (hence 'exceptions', i.e. 'exceptions to the rule', or norm/specification); if that should never be called without a valid function as a parameter argument, then it should go _BANG!_, so that you may react as quickly as possible (that is, new usage (badly done) wouldn't get through testing). If it would be acceptable to call it without, then it should _handle_ this by _maybe_ logging, but ultimately just continuing gracefully.

Comment: Well, I clearly don't understand error handling (or why it exists), I though a typeof check was continuing gracefully...